# store long value in android database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

How do I store long values in Android SQLite database ? I am trying to store the time(milliseconds) values which comes in long type format .

Answer (score 55):

An INTEGER column will handle long values.

From the SQLite site:

> INTEGER. The value is a signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8
>   bytes depending on the magnitude of the value.

[Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can define a column with Integer datatype. For more info go through this [link](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about sign, store it as INT8.   It's 8 bytes (64 bits) unsigned.  Or, convert to/from string.

Comment: INT8 will be converted to INTEGER in sqlite. (Or, at least that's how I understood the affinity section)