# how to define long in SQLite

Tags: android, database, sqlite, database-design

I need to create table column which contains data of type long, what am trying is to create column like this

```
+other columns

KEY_DATE_CREATED + " LONG OR something else**(DONT KNOW HOW TO DEFINE IT)**"

+other columns
```

what i'm trying to pass to that column is this below, which is from type long.

```
long dateM = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
```

tnx a lot!

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html. there is no Long type. You can use Integer

Answer (score 2):

An INTEGER column will handle long values.

From the [SQLite site](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html):

> INTEGER. The value is a signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8
>   bytes depending on the magnitude of the value.

Comment: nice copy/paste http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12584539/store-long-value-in-android-database

Comment: yup, it was just as quick as adding a link