# Why does my List<Long> contain integers?

Tags: java, android, android-room

So, I have the following method which is faking a database locally:

```
public class TestClassDao implements ClassDao {

    // ...

    private static List<ClassDto> classes = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public List<ClassDto> getClassesByIds(List<Long> classIds) {
        List<ClassDto> results = new ArrayList<>();

        for (ClassDto classInstance : classes) {
            if (classIds.contains(classInstance.getId())) {
                results.add(classInstance);
            }
        }

        return cloner.deepClone(results);
   }

   //...

}
```

I was puzzled, because the results were always coming back empty. I stepped through the debugger in Android Studio, and found that the contains check is always returning `false` even when the right ID is known to be present.

Tracing *that* back with the debugger, I found what I suspect to be the culprit: according to the debugger, `List<Long> classIds` contains **Integer**  objects. What gives? I'm not sure how to debug this any further.

EDIT:

Here's the debugger output the question is based on:
[image]

EDIT 2:

Here's how the test data is being loaded into the data store, you can see I am correctly passing `Long` values:

The below method is called by a method which does a similar thing for schools, and then persisted via a method in the test DAO.

```
public static ClassDto getClassTestData(int classId) {
    ClassDto classDto = new ClassDto();

    switch (classId) {
        case 1:
            classDto.setId(1L);
            classDto.setName("207E - Mrs. Randolph");
            classDto.setTeacher(getTeacherTestData());
            classDto.setStudents(getStudentsTestData());
            return classDto;
        case 2:
            classDto.setId(2L);
            classDto.setName("209W - Mr. Burns");
            classDto.setTeacher(getTeacherTestData());
            return classDto;
        case 3:
            classDto.setId(3L);
            classDto.setName("249E - Mr. Sorola");
            classDto.setTeacher(getTeacherTestData());
            return classDto;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

EDIT 3:

Here is the DAO where the school information is being persisted/retrieved from. The problem is occuring somewhere between the time that the data is inserted and the time it is removed. It goes in with type `Long` and comes out with Type `Int`

```
@Dao
public interface SchoolDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM schools")
   List<SchoolDto> getAllSchools();

    @Insert
    void insertSchool(SchoolDto schoolDto);

    }
```

Comment: Does getId() return a `Long`?

Comment: Yes, the code (for the getter) is here:

`public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }`

Comment: The tool you are using to perform the query is producing an `Integer` object for the column in question.  You need to either use a list of Integers or tell the db access tool that you want the value to be a Long.

Comment: Howe are you populating the `List`? Are they `Long` when they go into the list?

Comment: `classIds` is a parameter, and isn't changed by this method, so the integers are in there when it is passed in. I would guess there is a raw reference to the list somewhere, and something like `list.add(123)` is happening instead of `123L`.

Comment: `private List<Long> classIds;` is the field in a class called `SchoolDto` where these IDs are coming from.

Comment: For clarification, some of these entities are being loaded via Google's Room ORM for Android (with a REAL DAO implementation) - however, some of them are being loaded by a mock DAO implementation (like the above in the question).

Comment: @AndyTurner wouldn't that not compile?

Comment: @Airhead it would if `list` is a raw-typed reference.

Comment: @Airhead Where does the `classIDs` list come from? May be this is simple a bug of dynamically generated code at runtime? As the generics can't be checked at runtime  dynamically generated code could just fill your list with `Integer` objects...

Comment: @robert, the class ids is intialized with this line `schoolDto.setClassIds(Arrays.asList(1L, 2L, 3L));` and then the schoolDto is popped in the local database. The value is later retrieved from the local database. The ids are retrieved from the `SchoolDto` and then passed as shown above to get the info about the classes the school contains.

Comment: @Robert I see now upon inspection in the debugger, that the ids list being returned in the classDto is contains integers. So we can now identify a slightly earlier point where the problem is detected. This still begs the question, why? I am investigating now.

Comment: See my 3rd edit edit above...

Comment: Post the ClassDto class, you sure you declared the field as Long? an Long assignment at a an int will be a int

Comment: @Marcos Here's the relevant snippet

`@Entity(tableName = "classes")
public class ClassDto {

    @PrimaryKey
    private Long id;`

Comment: @Airhead have you tried querying the id column in sql? I think there is an implicit cast here.

Comment: Ohh. i got, the List of the argument is of integers

Comment: it may be just type erasure and optimization somehow

Comment: Change ur test to add a value that is Long.MAX_VALUE

Comment: I have solved the issue - see my answer for explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, what a nightmare. I have found the culprit.

I had created a `TypeConverter` to turn a `List<Integer>` to into a string (and back) so that it can be stored in a single column in the DB in room without having to modify the existing DTOs. However, when I switched over to using `Long` types as IDs, I failed to convert a *single* generic argument below in the converter; look carefully at the following code:

```
public class IdsListConverter {

    @TypeConverter
    public List<Long> idsFromString(String value) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        } else {
            Type resultType = new TypeToken<List<Integer>>(){}.getType();
            return gson.fromJson(value, resultType);
        }
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public String idsToString(List<Long> ids) {
        if (ids == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            return gson.toJson(ids);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: "look carefully" Please indicate what you did to fix it.

Comment: `Type resultType = new TypeToken<List<Integer>>(){}.getType();` should have had the generic changed to `List<Long>`

Comment: So, state that in the answer, don't leave readers who don't know what they should be "looking carefully" for wondering. Also, note that `gson.getAdapter(new TypeToken<List<Integer>>(){}).fromJson(value)` would have been a type-safe option (assuming this is a `com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken`).

Answer (score 1):

[It looks like](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49823203/3788176) you found your problem:

```
Type resultType = new TypeToken<List<Integer>>(){}.getType();
return gson.fromJson(value, resultType);
```

(in a method returning `List<Long>`) whereas it should have been:

```
Type resultType = new TypeToken<List<Long>>(){}.getType();
```

There is a type-safe way to write this which would have picked up the problem at compile time:

```
TypeToke<List<Integer>> resultTypeToken = new TypeToken<List<Integer>>() {};
return gson.getAdapter(resultTypeToken).fromJson(value);
```

This wouldn't have compiled, because the return statement's type is incompatible with the method's return type.

It might be worth looking for other occurrences of `fromJson` so you can migrate them and see if there are other problems you haven't found yet!

Comment: Excellent answer! Had no idea I could do that.

Answer (score 0):

You look at wrong variables. ClassDao instance is below, you can see "{Long@6495} "1". But the Integer "1" you spread is the element of ClassIds which is omitted in your code. You are sure ClassIds is List(), when adding element, you should do  classIds.add(new Long(1)).

Comment: I intialize the list with the following line before sticking it in the local DB `schoolDto.setClassIds(Arrays.asList(1L, 2L, 3L));`

Comment: When you save your classids to database, can you find out the data type in database? because there's no `long` type in sqlite

Comment: It's done with the Room ORM, so I would assume it handles that?

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/a/12584590/3908814 we know sqlite use integer to save long. I suggest you try to initlize your classIds with strong convertion to long when fetching from database.

Comment: Do you mean manually cast from int to long on retrieving from the database?

Comment: Could the issue be coming from using `Long` instead of `long`? Autoboxing maybe not handled correctly by Room?

Comment: yes, cast integer to long. Then create Long object.

Comment: In your Edit 2, why parameter classId is `int`. Please update.

Comment: It's a int because you can't use Long in a switch statement; it's just a for-loop index variable. It's value isn't used in insertion.

Comment: Sure I missed. And so you have some code to cast your classId to `int`

Answer (score -1):

For future reference, this list of casting rules will help you. In essence, I believe there is/was an implicit casting conflict.

```
byte –> short –> int –> long –> float –> double
```

Comment: I appreciate the help, but it was not the issue. I have answered with what the problem actually was.